# Return data from checked elements in UITableView using Navigation button

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that show some elements on it.

The elements on the text field can be checked if the user clicks in any element.

I have the code for that and it works perfectly.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let foods = ["tomato", "cheese", "bread", "apple"]
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView:UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "DONE", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.avancar(sender:)))
    }
    
    @objc func avancar(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("DONE button clicked")
        print("myTableView.numberOfSections: \(myTableView.numberOfSections)")
        print("myTableView.numberOfRows: \(myTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))")
        
        for i in 0..<foods.count {
            if tableView.cellForRow(at: [0, i])?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none {
                print("item \(i) is UNchecked")
            } else {
                print("item \(i) is checked")
            }
        }
        
        
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foods.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = foods[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("x: \(foods[indexPath.row])")
        print(indexPath)
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        } else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        }
    }
    
}
```

But what I want now is to return a string with all elements that are checked to a UITextField inside a UIViewController.

I want to put the following behaviour on it, when a user clicks on the TextField, the user must be redirected to a UITableView that show elements that can be checked it.

After the user click in any number of elements of the UITableView, the user will click on the DONE button that will get the text(string) of all checked elements in return it to the UITextField.

How can I return a String to the UITextField in the UIViewController.

Below you can find the images of the screen that I create.

[image]

Edit

I put another screenshot to show what my code is doing now.

[image].

I want to return the text that is checked, not selected.

ANOTHER EDIT

I was able to get the String result of the elements checked using the code below, now I still need to know how to return the data to the previous UIViewController

```
@objc func avancar() {
        textToReturn = ""
        
        for i in 0..<foods.count {
            if tableView.cellForRow(at: [0, i])?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none {
                print("item \(i) is UNchecked")
            } else {
                textToReturn = textToReturn + foods[i] + ", "
                
            }
        }
        
        print("textToReturn: \(textToReturn)")
        
    }
```

Comment: What about using: `if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows { indexPaths.forEach { print("Index path: \($0) is selected with text: food[$0.row] }`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows

Comment: @Larme The problem that I have is to return the String to the UIViewController. Your code was able to get the selected cell, but I want to get back the checked cell. I edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom struct to maintain the selected status. This is the most convenient way

```
struct Food {
    let name : String
    var isSelected = false
}
```

Declare the datasource

```
let foods = [Food(name:"tomato"), 
             Food(name:"cheese"), 
             Food(name:"bread"), 
             Food(name:"apple")]
```

In `cellForRow` set the accessory view according to the `isSelected` property

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foods.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = foods[indexPath.row].name
    cell.accessoryType = foods[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelect` toggle the `isSelected` property in the data source and reload the row

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("x: \(foods[indexPath.row])")
    foods[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

In the action method `filter` the selected items, `map` them to their name and `join` them to one string.

```
@objc func avancar(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("DONE button clicked")
        
    let selectedItems = foods.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}.joined(separator: ", ")
    print(selectedItems)
}
```