# Xcode tableView didSelectRowAt not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

What I expect to happen when I click on a row: the text from the row gets printed instantly, the grey background flashes, the checkmark comes on/off instantly.

What actually happens: the text doesn't print until I click on a different row, the grey background doesn't flash, the checkmark only updates when I click on a different row.

[image]

```
let itemArray = ["Find Mike", "Buy Eggos", "Destroy Demagorgon"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    print(itemArray[indexPath.row])
    
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    } else {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

I can't tell why this isn't working the way I expect. I used print statements to check when the function was getting called, but I can't get past the fact that it just isn't calling when I expect it to.

## Answer

It was a syntax error, I was using didDeselectRowAt rather than didSelectRowAt.

Comment: You implemented *did**De**selectRowAt*. Nevertheless never modify the **view** (the cell), modify the **model** and tell the **controller** to update the UI.

Comment: Wow, that was it, just a syntax error. Thanks, that was driving me crazy.

Comment: Your approach is wrong anyway. Cells are reused and lose the information when the user scrolls. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523075/return-data-from-checked-elements-in-uitableview-using-navigation-button/67524004#67524004

Comment: Haha, been there, done that. Those method look very much alike on a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement both `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt`? On `didSelect`, turn on the checkmark. On `didDeselect`, turn it off.

If you need the flags data, it is better to store it in a model (in your code, they are stored in the UI/cells), and keep the model & cells synchronised.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better approach to simply toggle the state in your model. Add a flag to your model class that represents the current state.

Then in your `didDeselectRowAt` set the flag and call tableView.reloadItems with the clicked `indexPath`.

In your `cellForRow` load the corresponding model object and set the `accessoryType` based on the property on your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Use tableView's reloaddata(). I presume, this will fix the problem.